# Netbeans + php, Why autocomplete and CTRL+Click don't work?

Tags: php, netbeans, autocomplete

So, problem is strange:

1. ctrl+click works only for native php methods and functions and don't :
   [image: Problem is here]
   For this example I used Laravel 5.5 + https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper, which should add methods of frameworks.
2. Autocomplite don't work even for methods of class in same file. What should I do to enable this feature?

Ubuntu 16.04
Product Version: NetBeans IDE 8.1 (Build 20151231-debian-8.1)
Updates: NetBeans IDE is updated to version NetBeans 8.1 Patch 1 
I tried with Laravel, Yii2 and Zend Framework applications. What should I do to fix that?

Comment: Are these projects installed with composer? Do the vendor packages appear in the source tree? You should make it able to index those packages too.

Comment: Yes, all projects are installed by composer, vendor packages in source tree

Comment: I've only experienced this issue then only when the "indexing" process is not yet finished. There should be a progress bar below which tells you the  actual state. It may be slow without an SSD with the source on.
If it is finished my other guess would be you've put your IDE helper thingy into a wrong place.
If it still can't work I'm unfortunately out of idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution helps me:

I used a version from rep (apt-get install netbeans) and php was installed as a plugin. When I installed php-version

http://download.netbeans.org/netbeans/8.2/final/bundles/netbeans-8.2-php-linux-x86.sh
http://download.netbeans.org/netbeans/8.2/final/bundles/netbeans-8.2-php-linux-x64.sh

, everything start works correct.