# NetBeans 20, Ctrl + Left Click don't work (windows 11)

Tags: netbeans, click, ctrl

I have Windows 11 and installed NetBeans 20 to work at my PHP project, but Ctrl + Left Click just doesn't work.
I also have another computer with windows 10 and work fine.

I tried:

- Downgrade to NetBeans 19
- Downgrade JDK from 21 to 17
- Downgrade to NetBeans 12.6
- Install nb-javac plugin
- install CakePHP plugin
- Delete AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache*
- Restart my PC
- Add path folder
- Create a new NetBeans project

Some visited topics:

- [Netbeans 7.2 Ctrl + Click doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12641752/netbeans-7-2-ctrl-click-doesnt-work)
- [Netbeans + php, Why autocomplete and CTRL+Click don't work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46889577/netbeans-php-why-autocomplete-and-ctrlclick-dont-work)
- ["Go to declaration" does not work in Netbeans PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8369807/go-to-declaration-does-not-work-in-netbeans-php)

Thanks guys.